\cref refers to lemmas as theorems
I think I found another problem with \cref after the November update. I defined two \newtheorem environments called plemma and ptheorem. Now, I let the numbering of plemma depend on ptheorem. If I refer to plemma, it displays as if I were referring to ptheorem. Just run the following code in TeXstudio to see what I mean:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref,cleveref}

\newtheorem{ptheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{plemma}[ptheorem]{Lemma}

\crefname{ptheorem}{THEOREM}{THEOREMS}
\crefname{plemma}{lemma}{lemmas}


\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{A}
\begin{plemma}\label{lem}
    XXX
\end{plemma}

Use \cref{lem}.

\end{document}

Instead of displaying lemma 1, it displays THEOREM 1
How can I fix this without switching the usepackages?

Yes, pretty sure it worked before

very sorry. this did work before, you're right.

Indeed, this used to work, i.e., it generated the correct text label ("lem"), until very recently. For reference, could you provide information about which TeX distribution and which versions of the LaTeX kernel and of the cleveref package you employ? FWIW, your code generates the wrong text label on my system as well (MacTeX2024, updated thru 2024/11/04; LaTeX kernel 2024-11-01; L3 programming layer 2024-11-02; cleveref 2018/03/27 v0.21.4).

This is mentioned somewhat obliquely in the documentation for amsthm, but because cleveref works from the counter name and you’re reusing the theorem counter for lemmas, it isn’t able to automatically figure out what you want.
The solution is to modify you \label command to specify that this is meant to be a lemma explicitly, so you would write
\label[plemma]{lem}

to indicate that this is a lemma and not a theorem.

Many thanks, this approach works indeed. But I am sure that before the update all my crefs were working properly. I will use your suggested workaround :-)

Well the best solution is to make the alias explicit. This would work with and without amsthm (something that the original cleveref code does not, it only supports amsthm):
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newtheorem{ptheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{plemma}[ptheorem]{Lemma}

\AddToHook{env/plemma/begin}{\crefalias{ptheorem}{plemma}}

\crefname{ptheorem}{THEOREM}{THEOREMS}
\crefname{plemma}{lemma}{lemmas}


\begin{document}
\section{A}\label{A}
\begin{plemma}\label{lem}
    XXX
\end{plemma}

\begin{ptheorem}\label{theorem}
    XXX
\end{ptheorem}


Use \cref{lem}, \cref{theorem}

\end{document}

If you want to reinstate the patch you can do this:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newtheorem{ptheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{plemma}[ptheorem]{Lemma}

%\AddToHook{env/plemma/begin}{\crefalias{ptheorem}{plemma}}

\makeatletter
\def\cref@thmoptarg[#1]#2#3#4{%
    \ifhmode\unskip\unskip\par\fi%
    \normalfont%
    \trivlist%
    \let\thmheadnl\relax%
    \let\thm@swap\@gobble%
    \thm@notefont{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}%
    \thm@headpunct{.}% add period after heading
    \thm@headsep 5\p@ plus\p@ minus\p@\relax%
    \thm@space@setup%
    #2% style overrides
    \@topsep \thm@preskip               % used by thm head
    \@topsepadd \thm@postskip           % used by \@endparenv
    \def\@tempa{#3}\ifx\@empty\@tempa%
      \def\@tempa{\@oparg{\@begintheorem{#4}{}}[]}%
    \else%
      \refstepcounter[#1]{#3}%  <<< cleveref modification
      \@namedef{cref@#3@alias}{#1}% added
      \def\@tempa{\@oparg{\@begintheorem{#4}{\csname the#3\endcsname}}[]}%
    \fi%
    \@tempa}%
\makeatother

\crefname{ptheorem}{THEOREM}{THEOREMS}
\crefname{plemma}{lemma}{lemmas}


\begin{document}
\section{A}\label{A}
\begin{plemma}\label{lem}
    XXX
\end{plemma}

\begin{ptheorem}\label{theorem}
    XXX
\end{ptheorem}


Use \cref{lem}, \cref{theorem}

\end{document}



What is that patch in the second piece of code you posted, i.e., what does it do? And which of the two solutions is the advisable one?

@Bubaya Well as I wrote "the best solution is to make the alias explicit". So I would use the first. The patch rewrites an internal definition of amsthm and will break if amsthm changes something (e.g. it is not compatible with the tagging project).

It works if you use the aliascnt trick.
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{amsthm,hyperref,cleveref}

\newtheorem{ptheorem}{Theorem}
\newaliascnt{plemma}{ptheorem}
\newtheorem{plemma}[plemma]{Lemma}
\aliascntresetthe{plemma}

\crefname{ptheorem}{THEOREM}{THEOREMS}
\crefname{plemma}{lemma}{lemmas}


\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{A}
\begin{plemma}\label{lem}
    XXX
\end{plemma}

Use \cref{lem}.

\end{document}


This is done automatically by keytheorems (which, disclaimer, I wrote).
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{keytheorems,hyperref,cleveref}

\newkeytheorem{ptheorem}[
  name=Theorem,
  refname={theorem,theorems},
  Refname={Theorem,Theorems},
  ]
\newkeytheorem{plemma}[
  name=Lemma,
  sibling=ptheorem,
  refname={lemma,lemmas},
  Refname={Lemma,Lemmas},
  ]

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{A}
\begin{plemma}\label{lem}
    XXX
\end{plemma}

Use \cref{lem}.

\begin{ptheorem}\label{thm}
    XXX
\end{ptheorem}

Use \cref{thm}.

\end{document}



Here is a way to redefine the \newtheorem command so that you get the old behaviuor again, at the cost of loading aliascnt.  The example below is for amsart or a document using amsthm, so that there is also the starred variant \newtheorem* defined.  In the comments is a version for standard LaTeX, which does not have the starred variant.

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\let\oldtheorem\newtheorem
% \RenewDocumentCommand{\newtheorem}{m o m O{}}{%
% \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\oldtheorem{#1}{#3}[#4]}%
% {\newaliascnt{#1}{#2}%
% \oldtheorem{#1}[#1]{#3}%
% \aliascntresetthe{#1}}%
% }
\RenewDocumentCommand{\newtheorem}{s m o m O{}}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}%
{\oldtheorem{#2}{#4}}%
{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\oldtheorem{#2}{#4}[#5]}%
{\newaliascnt{#2}{#3}%
\oldtheorem{#2}[#2]{#4}%
\aliascntresetthe{#2}}}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:one}
  Text.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
  \label{lem:three}
  Text.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:two}
  Text.
\end{theorem}

\Cref{thm:one}, \cref{lem:three}, \cref{thm:two}

\end{document}

